# Git merge reports file deleted when it's not

Tags: git

I have a master branch and a feature branch. Both contain the Bar.cs file. However when I try to merge feature into master, it reports that the file Bar.cs was deleted on the feature branch. But Bar.cs was never deleted on feature and as I said, both files are present on both branches.

A git log of the file Bar.cs on master returns the following:

```
commit daaf6bd6c8d2a38b839fae44234ceef2a0c9e188
Author: xxxx
Date:   Fri Jun 28 10:17:18 2013 +0000

    Renamed Foo.cs to Bar.cs
```

A git log of the file Bar.cs on feature returns the following:

```
commit 93dea9f7a2b9474c169bf8a49c5a721572a9d369
Author: xxxx
Date:   Fri Jul 5 16:14:46 2013 +0000

    Another change

commit de9fbe3ae13ccdac8a540c653af10abb1a2f1006
Author: xxxx
Date:   Tue Jul 2 16:03:43 2013 +0000

    Renamed Foo.cs to Bar.cs
```

As you can see, in feature I merged the change from master on Jul 2, then made one other change to the file on Jun 28.

When I try to merge, git says:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Bar.cs deleted in feature and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of Bar.cs left in tree.
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem during a merge between two branches synced from a SVN repository with the `git-svn` tool.

Some files were renamed on `master` branch and **updated** on `feature` branch, but git detected these files as **deleted** on the `feature` side:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Classes/A.m deleted in feature and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of Classes/A.m left in tree.
```

The solution was to change the merge strategy to `resolve` instead of the default `recursive`:

```
git merge -s resolve feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the problematic commits seem to be the exact same thing you can try interactively rebasing `feature` ontop `master`:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i master
```

an editor will pop up to let you chose wich commits to pick. Delete the line with the commit `de9fbe`. This will then re-apply all commits except the rename in `feature`.

Afterwards, merging can be done using

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
```

Comment: The commit de9fbe doesn't appear in the rebase editor... It does however appear in the log for feature. What happening?!?!

Comment: ok, rebase was smart enough to filter it out for you. Just do a regular `rebase`.

Comment: You mean, do a rebase onto to master instead of merging? I can't do that as the branch relates to a remove SVN branch and as far as I understand that would confuse SVN mightily.

Comment: I am tempted just to manually copy all of the files from the branch into master and be done with it, but I'm trying to use this an an opportunity to get to know git better and as such would like to understand what is happening.